# Peço desculpa a todos, mas quero fazer uma reclamação sobre downvoter?

Tags: debate

**RECLAMAÇÃO**

Só quero deixar bem claro que a minha reclamação sobre downvoter já é pertinente, eu não aguento mais receber votos sem merecer é parece que sempre é a mesma pessoa. Quero saber como devo proceder ( por favor, não me venha falar: a isso é normal ), poxa todos os dias alguém vêm do nada e retire uma voto da minha resposta sem ter nenhum motivo, aparente. A imagem abaixo que é dessa pergunta: [Randonizar resultados com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31161/11549), foi a resposta aceita na pergunta e hoje infelizmente eu acabei pegando, bem no momento.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realmente em mim há uma grande decepção nesse ponto, não vejo motivo para retirar votos de ninguém, porque isso desestimula os que são mais novos, mas, já removi votos de respostas que existe um caráter experiência própria e opiniões, como é a normalidade. A minha resposta abaixo é técnica já nesse ponto não vejo motivo porque o `script PHP` está correto, limpo, pequeno e perfeito.

Quais as atitudes que os responsáveis poderiam tomar?

Comment: Apesar da sua resposta solucionar o problema, ela não fornece uma explicação, por isso alguém pode ter negativado. Recomendo não levar para o lado pessoal e olhar por outra perspectiva ao invés de "perseguição".

Comment: Maria o Downvote não pode ser levado como ataque pessoal e simplesmente um voto negativo de alguém que não gostou da sua resposta. Eu quando tenho votos negativos tento melhorar a resposta. Se for necessário até a apago. Aqui a ideia é tentar ajudar o máximo de pessoas possíveis. Há que saber conviver com isso. A própria vida de trabalho é assim, haverá sempre alguém que não goste do seu trabalho.

Comment: @brasofilo não é duplicata!

Comment: @JorgeB. só apago quando realmente não está correto, agora tudo aquilo que é correto aqui é visto por alguns o inverso mais ou menos != Correto !!! Tem que mudar a mentalidade, tem que ter crescimento esse grupo não vai longe dessa forma!

Comment: @Maria pode estar correto, e ainda assim alguém achar incompleto ou mal explicada a resposta... Poderia passar aqui a tarde a dar-te motivos para downvotes e outra tarde a dar-te motivos para upvote, de qualquer resposta do SOpt.

Comment: @JorgeB. é corriqueiro não é nada passar uma tarde ou uma manhã, Votos contras ou Votos a favor são um lema aqui, mas, receber aquilo que não merece e uma comunidade achar isso normal isso que anda errado, inclusive esses dias teve um questionamento de downvoter que foi revertido ou seja, para uns é para os outros a coisa é bem diferente, porque, pode ser que não seja em sequencia, mas, é frequente em todas as minhas respostas.

Comment: @Maria falaste com os moderadores? Chegaste aqui toda enervada, já a insultar toda a gente. Relaxa, a melhor resposta é ignorar. Não é entrar em bate bocas. Muito menos insultar. NINGUÉM aqui esta contra você não, a não ser você mesma. (até me pós a escrever BR lol)

Comment: Lê bem o que as pessoas escrevem nas respostas e nos comentários, um tirando sarro daqui, outro falando em política de uso, outro que levou downvoter e foi revertido, e ai falam vai pro META resolver. e percebo que o meta é escrever e não adianta nada. com você @JorgeB. tenho respeito mas, com alguns eu já conheço muito bem como são, verdadeiros politicos do SO e olha que a primeira vez que eu entrei e agora a coisa caiu bastante viu, mas, muito mesmo! é preocupante!

Comment: Eles estão só a brincar, como todos fazemos uns com os outros. Eu também brinco. o SOpt não é uma rede social. Os downvotes fazem parte do site. No exemplo da sua resposta você não explica como e porque fez assim, só dá uma solução. Eu se não percebesse nada do assunto ia ficar a olhar para aquilo horas a tentar perceber o que era aquilo. Nem sempre a solução é a resposta.

Comment: Olha em Matemática, se puser num exame só a solução do problema, tira 0 na resposta. Eu próprio poderia dar -1. Não dou porque a MINHA política é -1 para respostas erradas, 0 para respostas incompletas e +1 para respostas certas(a meu ver) O que é certo para mim pode não ser para ti.

Comment: É preciso é ter muita calma e não levar nada a peito, se se sentir perseguida, abre aqui o tópico e fala com os moderadores. Eles vão investigar se é perseguição ou se é puro acaso os downvotes.

Comment: OK! @JorgeB. obrigada pelos seus esclarecimentos.

Comment: Tentei ser bem humorado pra tirar peso da situação, não funcionou muito bem... Então tentando ser construtivo aqui: das suas 48 respostas, [7 tiveram votos negativos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11549/maria?tab=reputation). Sim, pode ser que tenha alguém específico esteja te "perseguindo", mas não de maneira serial que possa ser detectada automaticamente pelo sistema. O mecanismo correto é você sinalizar uma das suas respostas e pedir uma investigação, ou então usar o formulário de contato linkado no rodapé da página. Eu sugiro você esperar mais um pouco e ver como se desenvolve isso.

Comment: @brasofilo só para contemplar foi retirado mais um voto, agora não me venha falar que estou assim achando que é normal, agora olha o que você disse para mim sobre a medalha de exclusão de resposta que tem um número excessivo de downvoter, eu não achei nunca que foi bem humorado, eu achei que tirou sarro mesmo e aqui é assim não vota na resposta, vota na pessoa e se fosse assim eu já tinha enchido várias resposta que são pura especulação e não o fiz.

Comment: Tem uma coisa que se chama "Efeito Meta": quando alguém abre alguma discussão sobre um post específico e a situação foge do controle, tem gente que vai lá no site principal e vota negativamente. Não tá certo, mas acontece e não tem muito que se possa fazer. . . . O primeiro comentário que o Orion fez aqui nesta pergunta, eu também já tinha te dado a dica e o JorgeB confirmou aqui encima. . . . Se tomei a liberdade de mencionar a medalha por deletar um post =< 3 é porque você não é uma estranha pra mim. Por favor, anote também meus parabéns acima pela medalha Capelo (:eu não tenho uma dessa:)

Comment: Não querendo ser chato, mas achei sua atitude meio infantil Maria.... isso é so um sistema de votação que não nos leva a lugar algum..... Se o autor da pergunta votou na sua pergunta como a melhor, então o que importa o que os outros acham e pensam?.... Como foi dito ai em cima, peça que investiguem o ocorrido, e não fique achando que é uma trama de perseguição.....

Comment: Seu modo de pensar é um problema para a comunidade MarceloBoni.
Existe sim usuários que reclamam por nada. Nesse caso, existe um padrão, e já é até conhecido como os maníacos dos downvoters.
Uma coisa é esclarecer para os usuários que a moderação ainda não tem uma solução para esse tipo de problema. Outra, é dar a entender que esse problema não existe. Seu comentário foi infeliz!

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff pra que ressuscitar esse tópico ? O comentário é de 3 anos atrás...

Comment: Concordo Perfeitamente com esse tópico mais aqui não temos voz...

Answer (score 15):

> "[...]parece que sempre é a mesma pessoa[...]"

Como você pode ter esta certeza toda se os votos são anônimos?

**Cuidado para não descontar a raiva na pessoa errada**. Se você supõe que seja algo pessoal, basta pedir para a moderação analisar sua suspeita. Eu também já recebi uma sequência de DOWNVOTES e **foram revertidos**.

---

> Orion eu vou sair do SO!, obrigada!
>
> Orion só para não ficar em branco é perseguição.! eu constatei

Não leve as coisas para o lado pessoal, o intuito da comunidade SO é *fazer o bem sem olhar a quem*. Ninguém é obrigado a gostar da sua reposta só porque você julga ser a melhor. O @Perdeu recebeu +6 e não teve a resposta escolhida... Acontece.

Quando participava de fóruns de internet não recebia **nem um obrigado**.

Desarme-se, pois ninguém consegue agradar todo mundo, ofereça uma resposta para uma pergunta com o seu melhor e pronto - ajudar por si só deveria ser a gratificação. Reputação massageia o ego mas também pode frustrar.

Comment: +1 Disse exatamente o que eu penso.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, parece não é dizer é a pessoa! eu acredito que você tenha entendido bem. Alguém no META é um jogo de palavras!

Answer (score -11):

Pelo menos alguém teve o bom senso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem encher de -1, mas, garanto não é clareza para todos e nem todos concordam! talvez alguns até são influenciados pela maioria